# Express with EJS Basiks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Please guide to solve the issue.

app.js

```
     app.get('/users', function(req, res){
User.find({},function (err, users) {
    console.log(users)
    res.render('users', { title: 'Users', users: users});
});
```

});

users.html

```
   <h1><%= title %></h1>
   <ul id="usersli">
   <% users.forEach(function(user){ 
console.log(user)
 %>
<li><%= user %> &lt;<%= user.age %>&gt;</li>
   <% }) %>
</ul>
```

Guide me to print name and age .

Here is O/P:

Users

```
     { _id: 534e4421e0035316b849d038, name: 'ayyappa', age: 26, status: 'Active' } <undefined>
     { _id: 534e55c9e0035316b849d039, name: 'Aravind', age: 26, status: 'Active' } <undefined>
```

Due to user is having an object of a record.

Comment: Sort of see it but not all of it. What do you actually want in the output?

Comment: Hi Neil, Apologize have you seen the given output. It is showing undefined for age. when ever i am trying to print user as it is fine and giving the output, while trying to print a single element from the same user object it is showing undefined.